# Extra next() for generator in `zip()`?

Tags: python, generator

Given,

```py
import itertools as it
def foo():
    idx = 0
    while True:
        yield idx
        idx += 1

k = foo()
```

When I use `zip()` as in the following,

```py
>>> list(zip(k,[11,12,13]))
[(0, 11), (1, 12), (2, 13)]
```

and then immediately after,

```py
>>> list(zip(k,[11,12,13]))
[(4, 11), (5, 12), (6, 13)]
```

Notice that the second zip should have started with `(3,11)` but it jumped to `(4,11)`
instead. It's as if there is another hidden `next(k)` somewhere. This does not happen when I use `it.islice`

```py
>>> k = foo()
>>> list(it.islice(k,6))
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

Notice `it.islice` is not missing the `3` term.

I am using Python 3.8.

Comment: `zip` iterates as long as there is something. It has to call `next` to find out that it is at the end. It called `next` on `k`, which succeeded, and then it called `next` on the other one, which failed. That is where it stopped. I see no other way to implement it.

Comment: And if you change to `zip([11, 12, 13], k)` I suspect it won't skip, since it detects the end of the list first.

Comment: In general, the iterator protocol only provides a way to *consume* the next element of an iterator, and no way to see what the next element *will* be.

Comment: The second argument lets `islice` stop consuming `k` at a known time, without having to consume an element to see if the iterator is exhausted.

Comment: FWIW, you will see the same behavior with `itertools.count`.

Comment: What is the question?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`zip` basically (and necessarily, given the design of the iterator protocol) works like this:

```
 # zip is actually a class, but we'll pretend it's a generator
 # function for simplicity.
 def zip(xs, ys):
     # zip doesn't require its arguments to be iterators, just iterable
     xs = iter(xs)
     ys = iter(ys)
     while True:
         x = next(xs)
         y = next(ys)
         yield x, y
```

There is no way to tell if `ys` is exhausted before an element of `xs` is consumed, and the iterator protocol doesn't provide a way for `zip` to put `x` "back" in `xs` if `next(ys)` raises a `StopIteration` exception.

Answer (score 1):

For the special case where one of the input iterables is [sized](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.abc.html#collections.abc.Sized), you can do a little better than `zip`:

```
import itertools as it
from collections.abc import Sized

def smarter_zip(*iterables):
    sized = [i for i in iterables if isinstance(i, Sized)]
    try:
        min_length = min(len(s) for s in sized)
    except ValueError:
        # can't determine a min length.. fall back to regular zip
        return zip(*iterables)
    return zip(*[it.islice(i, min_length) for i in iterables])
```

It uses [`islice`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.islice) to prevent [`zip`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip) from consuming more from each iterator than we know is strictly necessary. This `smarter_zip` will solve the problem for the case posed in the original question.

However, in the general case, there is no way to tell beforehand whether an iterator is exhausted or not (consider a generator yielding bytes arriving on a socket). If the shortest of the iterables is not sized, the original problem still remains. For solving the general case, you may want to wrap iterators in a class which remembers the last-yielded item, so that it can be recalled from memory if necessary.